# Download video from URL in Python

Tags: python, download

I am trying to download a video using the below code in Python.

```
import urllib
dwn_link = 'https://class.coursera.org/textanalytics-001/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=73'

file_name = 'trial_video.mp4' 
urllib.retrieve(dwn_link, file_name)
```

But this code downloads only 382 kb and video open with an error.

Any help?

Edit: I could download all .pdf files in this page using their download links, but there seems to be some issue with video files. Video does get downloaded int my local system, but with error

Comment: Does the website require you to be logged in to access the video?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i am already logged into coursera.

Comment: urllib.retrieve(dwn_link, file_name) should be
urllib.urlretrieve(dwn_link, file_name)

Comment: @user3035935 Python doesn't have your browser's credentials though. You'd have to set the HTTP headers manually in your code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Please refer to my edit in question. I don't think credentials is a issue.

Comment: The 382kB file is likely the HTML file that the site redirects to in order to prompt for authentication, so again please refer to the answers that say that.

Answer (score 42):

In python 3,

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_link, 'video_name.mp4')
```

It works for me and you can see the script at the following [link](https://github.com/ankitjain28may/pythonResources/tree/master/Download%20video%20from%20cmd%20using%20python)

Comment: Also, check out this answer to add a `progressbar` to visually see your download. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748105/how-to-use-progressbar-module-with-urlretrieve

Answer (score 12):

You can use the library requests:

```
def download_video_series(video_links): 

for link in video_links: 

    '''iterate through all links in video_links 
    and download them one by one'''

    # obtain filename by splitting url and getting  
    # last string 
    file_name = link.split('/')[-1]    

    print "Downloading file:%s"%file_name 

    # create response object 
    r = requests.get(link, stream = True) 

    # download started 
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f: 
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024): 
            if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk) 

    print "%s downloaded!\n"%file_name 

print "All videos downloaded!"
return
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have access to `urllib2` , you can use `urlopen` on the `url` , this would give back a `response` object , you can do `response.read()` to `read` the data and then write it to a file.

Example -

```
import urllib2
dwn_link = 'https://class.coursera.org/textanalytics-001/lecture/download.mp4?lecture_id=73'

file_name = 'trial_video.mp4' 
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(dwn_link)
with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
    f.write(rsp.read())
```

Also you need to make sure that you have authenticated to the server , if that is required for downloading the video.

I am not sure what kind of authentication `coursera.org` uses, but if its Basic HTTP Authentication (Which I highly doubt) , you can use -

```
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
top_level_url = "http://class.coursera.org/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(dwn_link)
```

Comment: urllib2 behaves exactly like urllib in terms of output.

May you  please specify which library has password_mgr object? I would like to try this one.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice password_mgr was not initialized , i ahve updated the code, its `password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()`

Comment: I added following commands at the end of your code:
    rsp = opener.open(dwn_link)

    with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
        f.write(rsp.read())

Unfortunately, output is still same. File of size 382 kb.

Answer (score 4):

To download that video from that Coursera class, you need to be:

1. signed into a session for Coursera.org
2. signed up for that class in Coursera.org

Once you do that, you can download the video after your HTTP client authenticates (with your username / password) and has a valid session.

Comment: dwn_link variable in the code is the required url. I am logged in the session with Coursera at the time when I am running this code

Answer (score 0):

To download a file with minimal memory footprint, you can use [`smart_open`](https://pypi.org/project/smart_open/).

The code becomes quite pythonic, and it keeps only a small portion of the file in memory at a time:

```py
# pip install smart_open[http]
from smart_open import open

def stream_uri(uri_in, uri_out, chunk_size=1 << 18):  # 256kB chunks
    """Write from uri_in to uri_out with minimal memory footprint."""
    with open(uri_in, "rb") as fin, open(uri_out, "wb") as fout:
        while chunk := fin.read(chunk_size):
            fout.write(chunk)

# from https to disk
stream_uri("https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/sample-video.mp4", "./sample-video.mp4")
# from s3 to ftp
stream_uri("s3://bucket1/example.pdf", "ftp://192.168.178.1:21/example.pdf")
```

They support a [range of protocols](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#transport-specific-options) which can be combined here.