# How to use progressbar module with urlretrieve

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

My **pyhton3** script downloads a number of images over the internet using **urlretrieve**, and I'd like to add a progressbar with a *completed percentage* and *download speed* for each download.

The [progressbar](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module seems like a good solution, but although I've looked through [their examples](http://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), and *example4* seems like the right thing, I still can't understand how to wrap it around the *urlretrieve*.

I guess I should add a third parameter:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('img_url', 'img_filename', some_progressbar_based_reporthook)
```

But how do I properly define it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think a better solution is to create a class that has all the needed state

```
import progressbar

class MyProgressBar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pbar = None

    def __call__(self, block_num, block_size, total_size):
        if not self.pbar:
            self.pbar=progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=total_size)
            self.pbar.start()

        downloaded = block_num * block_size
        if downloaded < total_size:
            self.pbar.update(downloaded)
        else:
            self.pbar.finish()
```

and call :

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('img_url', 'img_filename', MyProgressBar())
```

Answer (score 24):

The suggestion in the other answer did not progress for me past 1%. Here is a complete implementation that works for me on Python 3:

```
import progressbar
import urllib.request


pbar = None


def show_progress(block_num, block_size, total_size):
    global pbar
    if pbar is None:
        pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=total_size)
        pbar.start()

    downloaded = block_num * block_size
    if downloaded < total_size:
        pbar.update(downloaded)
    else:
        pbar.finish()
        pbar = None


urllib.request.urlretrieve(model_url, model_file, show_progress)
```

Comment: This actually worked really well. Thanks!

Comment: Another interesting solution with a more verbose update output is this one https://blog.shichao.io/2012/10/04/progress_speed_indicator_for_urlretrieve_in_python.html.

Answer (score 3):

The hook is defined as:

`urlretrieve(url[, filename[, reporthook[, data]]])`
"The third argument, if present, is a hook function that will be called 
once on establishment of the network connection and once after each block 
read thereafter. The hook will be passed three arguments; a count of blocks 
transferred so far, a block size in bytes, and the total size of the file. 
The third argument may be -1 on older FTP servers which do not return a 
file size in response to a retrieval request. "

So, you can write a hook as follows:

```
# Global variables
pbar = None
downloaded = 0

def show_progress(count, block_size, total_size):
    if pbar is None:
        pbar = ProgressBar(maxval=total_size)

    downloaded += block_size
    pbar.update(block_size)
    if downloaded == total_size:
        pbar.finish()
        pbar = None
        downloaded = 0
```

As a side note I strongly recommend you to use requests library which is a lot easier to use and you can iterate over the response with the `iter_content()` method.

Comment: Thank you, Doron. But I still do not understand how to use it. If I do `urllib.request.urlretrieve('img_url', 'img_filename', reporthook=show_progress())` then I get `TypeError` telling that function is missing all 3 required positional arguments.

Comment: Thanks again, I've looked up requests, and it is really better. So if I get you right - I can get filesize with `r.headers(['Content-length'])` and a current progress by adding chunks in `r.iter_content()`, right?

Comment: Yes. `for chunk in r.iter_content()` and inside you can do `downloaded += len(chunk)` and then update pbar with downloaded value. Don't forget to send the request with `stream=True`. See requests docs.

Comment: @Vasily If the answer satisfies your question please accept it. If not, I will happily edit it. Thanks.

Comment: On Python 3, this progress bar implementation never progressed past 1 percent. Here is my revised implementation that works for me:

`def show_progress(block_num, block_size, total_size):

    global pbar
    if pbar is None:
        pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=total_size)

    downloaded = block_num * block_size
    if downloaded < total_size:
        pbar.update(downloaded)
    else:
        pbar.finish()
        pbar = None

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(model_url, model_file, show_progress)`

Answer (score 3):

In python 3 you can achieve the same result without the progressbar module:

```
import urllib.request

# prepare progressbar
def show_progress(block_num, block_size, total_size):
    print(round(block_num * block_size / total_size *100,2), end="\r")

# use urlretrieve
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fileName, show_progress)
```

Comment: This did only work half for me. Unfrequently in the console theres blinking the progress but immediately disappearing..