# Download all mp4 videos from a website

Tags: linux, windows, download, wget

[This](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/nptel_download.php?subjectid=111105035) is the link of the lectures I want to download. It is tiresome to click each link and then download. I want to download all mp4 files from the website. How to achieve it. I have searched long enough to ask question here. I have downloaded Winwget but I am unable to figure out how to download files with are having .mp4 extension. I am comfortable with any OS windows 10 or ubuntu solution.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, for some sites, the `youtube-dl` python script.

1. open cmd prompt
2. type in there pip install `youtube-dl`
3. write the python script in cmd as follows:

   C:\Users\user_name>youtube-dl link

If it's a website that needs login, like Udemy, write

```
 C:\Users\user_name>youtube-dl -u user@gmail.com -p password course_link
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Python, here is a solution. It takes the content of the different link of the videos and stores it under "video_X.mp4", with X between 1 and 42:

```
import requests


for x in xrange(1,43):
    video_url = "http://nptel.ac.in/courses/download_mp4.php?subjectId=111105035&filename=mod01lec" + str(x).zfill(2)  + ".mp4"
    with open('video_' + str(x).zfill(2) + '.mp4', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(requests.get(video_url).content)
    pass
```

Comment: where this script is downloading files?

Comment: it is downloading the files in the folder you are executing your python script

Answer (score 0):

I used the following answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40553400/11786575) to write my Python code:

```
import urllib.request

### First, get a page source from Chrome inspector (press F12, select, copy and paste from "Elements"), paste the whole text here. The text should include a lot of text and also links to the mp4 video files.

filename = 'C:\\file_location...\\...\\...\\page_source_f12.txt'

### Write everything from the previous text file that includes .mp4 to a list
list_1 = []
with open(filename, "r", encoding='utf-8') as myFile:
    lines = myFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if ".mp4" in line:
            a = ((str(line)).lstrip()) ### and possibly other data modification to remove "href" etc. from the text lines
            print(a)
            list_1.append(a)

### Use the list to write a new file including only the video links
with open('C:\\...\\video_links.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as myFile2:
    for i in list_1:
        myFile2.write(str(i) + "\n")

### Use urllib.request to download every video file from the links in your list
counter = 0
for url_link in list_1:
    if "https" in url_link:
        print(url_link)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_link, "video" + str(counter) + ".mp4")
        print("------NOW DOWNLOADED: video" + str(counter) + ".mp4------")
        counter += 1
print("*****COMPLETE******")

# If you are using vscode, the videos are downloaded to the folder where you run the code in (the fila path shown in the terminal)
```