# What is the best way to batch download videos from teachable.com in Python?

Tags: python

I have got access to a course on teachable.com but this access is time-bound. If I wanted to keep the videos what is the best way to download them using Python, much like coursera-dl or youtube-dl?

I have tried the urlretriever method but it doesn't seem to download the video file but some video-like file that can't be played.

I have tried using this with no success
[Download video from URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953104/download-video-from-url-in-python/40553400)

The expected output is a list of mp4 files. I can then extend it to organise the files by modules.

Comment: youtube-dl is Python and I've found it pretty easy to write code that uses it previously, mostly to get DASH manifests that I could deal with myself.  what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this package: https://github.com/barakagb/gb-dl

You can install it using: `pip install gb-dl`