# How to download a video url that starts with CDN in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download a video from this URL:
//cdn.muscleandstrength.com/video/reversegripbentoverdumbbellrow.mp4

But when I do it with requests I am only getting an HTML markup. Here is my code:

```py
response = requests.get("https://www.muscleandstrength.com/video/highinvertedrow.mp4", allow_redirects=True)
with open("data/video.mp4", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953104/download-video-from-url-in-python

Comment: No, I already saw it before. It gives 403 status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script downloads the video and saves it as `video.mp4`. It's necessary to specify `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```
import requests


url = 'https://cdn.muscleandstrength.com/video/reversegripbentoverdumbbellrow.mp4'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
    
with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f_out:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f_out.write(chunk)
```