# Scraping a Video from a website and downloading it as mp4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, video-streaming

I am trying to scrape this [webiste](https://streamable.com/g6f986) and download the soccer goal that is in it. I saw this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979489/how-to-download-a-video-url-that-starts-with-cdn-in-python) and I tried the solution and it still does not work.

Here is the code I have done

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# specify the URL of the archive here
url = 'https://cdn-cf-east.streamable.com/video/mp4/g6f986.mp4p'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
    
with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f_out:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    print(r)
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f_out.write(chunk)
```

when I printed the request it showed me 403 and because of that the video will not open or get downloaded, any thoughts on how I can download the video?

Comment: Try adding an user-agent header to the request.

Answer (score 2):

Use this below url.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# specify the URL of the archive here
url = 'https://cdn-cf-east.streamable.com/video/mp4/g6f986.mp4?Expires=1621994280&Signature=IqySuJxyVi9pCmC~JUhl-iyp-LmG6OiAFfQeu-~-a55osCfu9VrksEhzaQzJlMxAHcSt1R4j9Pt-G8sblQeFt3UtGqY-neHJkC4mUxuHjxGWAWdksyiAxkMb8DYRLkvIseUfkbKbeO6Dt807QwMkspFmXYdzljm8DLho6nMQfC--jtfy8B2gONhA9YUmK2o~fUHwTHzTXXqNGct2hQl-B9cFLDBdj8LXWTj-75YInwWxLwtoenKK~qLahGtJXKXvxTVltxMvUYXXvP9F~WfhNIhNqns1JKrrrqJ~N1XunZHCv~IVJyzOEvrn2G4J5LMIn~dcEZ9frV3APHsE4D~HQA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIEYUVEN4EVB2OKEQ'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}

with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f_out:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    print(r)
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f_out.write(chunk)
```

Comment: can you please show the code you did to scrape this specific link and thanks!

Comment: I found the this url in chrome Developer Tool -> Network -> XHR.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you extract the video link from Streamable if you want to in a programmatic way

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# specify the URL of the archive here
url = "https://streamable.com/a50s3e"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Pull all text from the BodyText div
video = soup.find_all('video')

temp = video[0].get("src")

url = "https:"+temp

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}

with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f_out:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    print(r)
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f_out.write(chunk)
```